# Why after creating a table and writing data, restart the cnosdb and data will be lost with probability

Tags: cnosdb

### DDL

statement ok

alter database public set ttl '1000000d';

statement ok

drop table if exists gis_loc;

statement ok

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gis_loc(loc string);

### Query

prepare data

```
INSERT gis_loc(TIME, loc)

VALUES

('1999-12-31 00:00:00.000', 'POINT(0 0)'),

('1999-12-31 00:00:00.005', 'POINT(0 1)'),

('1999-12-31 00:00:00.010', 'POINT(0 2)'),

('1999-12-31 00:00:10.015', 'POINT(0 3)'),

('1999-12-31 00:00:10.020', 'POINT(0 4)'),

('1999-12-31 00:10:00.025', 'POINT(0 5)'),

('1999-12-31 00:10:00.030', 'POINT(0 6)'),

('1999-12-31 01:00:00.035', 'POINT(0 7)');
```

restart CnosDB. select * from gis_loc, empty